# How to handle transitions in container size in OpenLayers 3

Tags: css, css-transitions, openlayers-3

When an OpenLayers 3 map is resized, the contents of the map are stretched to fit the new map size. This is typically fixed by calling `map.UpdateSize()` after the change for the map to adapt.

However, I'm wondering how to achieve a smooth transition for the map contents when animating the width of the map.

[Here is a minimal example of the problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/47darogr/2/)

The map resizes in a very unpleasant way before the update happens.

I figured out that changing the `ol.Map` `renderer` to `'dom'` fixes the issue, but unfortunately this is not an option for me.

Comment: I'm fairly certain there is no way to marry the two.  You would need to use javascript to implement your transition (e.g. [using requestAnimationFrame or similar](https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/vjnm4n15/)).  Personally I like [GSAP](http://greensock.com/).

Comment: Quick & dirty: https://jsfiddle.net/b7wLk0wd/

Comment: Yeah that works, thanks. It is really a very rough solution though; I was hoping for something more robust.